# Using Powershell into C# to find out installed windows Features on WindowsServer2012

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell-4.0

I am trying to fetch the Installed Windows Features using powershell in C# code.But unable to get them.The code I am writing is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Runspace run = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            run.Open();
            PowerShell power = PowerShell.Create();
            power.Runspace = run;

           power.AddScript(" $d = get-date; $s = 'Hi How are you ?'; $name='mukul'; $get=(Get-WindowsFeature -name File-Services).Installed; " +
                  "$d; $s; $name; $get");
            foreach (PSObject result in power.Invoke())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(result.BaseObject.ToString() + "\n");   
            }
        }
```

The code works fine till `$name` but giving `null reference` exception at `$get`. What is causing that?

Comment: What version of Powerhsell is on the machine when you are running this code?

Comment: I am using powershell 4.0,net framework 4.5,Windows Server 2012 r2 64-bit.

Comment: If you log in that machine, will you get any result if running `Get-WindowsFeature File-Services`? Probably the machine is a Hyper-V server and does not have this feature listed, so your script asks for `$null.installed` and gets an exception.